# How do I return a list without any errors? 'NoneType' Error

Tags: python, list

Trying to create an accumulative function that returns a list with the value of n, occurring k amount of times.

```
def create_list_accum(n,k,lst):
    if len(lst) == n:
    return lst
    return create_list_accum(n,k,lst.append(k))

def create_list(n,k):
    lst = []
    create_list_accum(n,k,lst)
```

I keep getting an builtins.TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len().
Why is this happening? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Sharing your code snippet that arrived at the error message will help people debug your program rather than just posting the functions itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lst.append(k)` doesnt return anything, so when you pass it into `create_list_accum(n,k,lst)` as the `lst` parameter, your code is tries to do `len(None)`.

Try this instead:

```
def create_list_accum(n,k,lst):
    if len(lst) == n:
        return lst

    lst.append(k)
    return create_list_accum(n,k,lst)
```

Comment: Hey Loocid, thanks for helping me out, but now the function does not return anything?

Comment: @NoahRamuscak Do you mean `create_list(n,k)` doesnt return anything? If so, its because you need to add `return lst` to the bottom.

Comment: @Loocide ah yes I am very silly. Sorry, I am new to programming. Thank you so much Loocid much appreciated.